# How to access (index) a name/column by its name?

Tags: r, indexing

Let's assume we have

```
x <- 1:3
names(x) <- c("has", "some", "names")
```

and we want to rename one of these names, say `some` by `good`. If we know the index, we can do this:

```
names(x)[2] <- "good"
```

What I'm trying to find out is how to access the name `"some"` by its name. Intuitively:

```
names(x)["some"] <- "good"
```

But this does not work, since `names(x)` does not have "names" itself (i.e. the left hand side is `NULL`). So I tried to set the "names" of `names(x)`:

```
names(names(x)) <- names(x)
```

Which gives no error, but `names(x)` still does not have "names" => still no access by text possible... So my question is: How can I set the "names of names"?

Note: I'm asking mainly for educational purposes to better understand how indexing by strings works. There are obviously ways to achieve this without setting "names of names", maybe like this:

```
x <- ifelse(names(x) == "some", "good", names(x))
```

Comment: `names(x)[names(x) == "some"]` or `names(x)[grepl("some", names(x))]` are a couple of possibilities

Comment: there's also `plyr::rename`